# UWP уведомление из фонового потока

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Пишу приложение UWP и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне требуется периодически показывать пользователю  уведомления, те что отображаются в шторке не подходят. Уведомление должно полностью блокировать рабочий процесс пока оно не будет закрыто. Хотел реализовать это через IBackgroundTask фоновый процесс. Но так не получается. Подскажите как можно это реализовать.

Comment: Не думаю, что это вообще возможно

Answer (score 1):

По описанию проблемы, похоже на то, что вам нужен MessageDialog.

```
await (new MessageDialog("Заглавие", "Содержимое")).ShowAsync();
```